# PaintComponent in JPanel not being called

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, jpanel, paintcomponent

I'm writing an Java Application and trying to paint an BufferedImage. In my main, the JFrame is being created and the JPanel is being created and is being added to the JFrame. There is also a Thread being started for repainting, but it shows nothing and my System.out.println() in the paintComponent isn't called, too. I've googled this a lot, but i found nothing to solve my problem.

What am i doing wrong and why is it wrong???

My Code:

The main + Thread:

```
public class Main extends Thread
{
    public static Frame frame = new Frame();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IllegalStateException, IOException
    {
        frame.activePanel = new LoginPanel();
        frame.add(frame.activePanel);

        new Main();
    }

    public Main()
    {
        this.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            if(Main.frame.activePanel != null)
                Main.frame.activePanel.repaint();

            try{Thread.sleep(15);}catch(InterruptedException e){}
        }
    }
}
```

The JFrame:

```
public class Frame extends JFrame
{
    public JPanel activePanel = null;

    public Frame()
    {
        super();

        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setBounds(this.getToolkit().getScreenSize().width / 2 - 640,this.getToolkit().getScreenSize().height / 2 - 400,1279,799);
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setUndecorated(true);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

and the JPanel:

```
public class LoginPanel extends JPanel
{
    BufferedImage loginImg;

    public LoginPanel() throws IOException
    {
        loginImg  = ImageIO.read(new File("src/images/Login.PNG"));
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {System.out.println("painting");
        g.drawImage(loginImg, 0, 0, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: not sure about it... but what happens if you don't Override paintComponent?

Comment: The same, I get a white/grey window. Sadly, this way I can't check if it is called.

Comment: Woah, woah! You have to be careful when dealing with threads in Swing, also you don't need to call repaint periodically, you'd  want to call repaint if you add/remove components after they've been painted. Please read [how to use threads in swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) you can only modify the GUI from the [Event dispatch thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).

Comment: Thanks,  i'll read those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks to me like you are adding the panel to the frame AFTER the frame is visible. When you do this the layout manager is not invoked and the size of the panel is (0, 0) so there is nothing to paint.

Restructure your code. The creation of the panel should be done in the Frame class, not Main class.

Also, use a better name instead of Frame. The AWT already has a class called Frame so you name is very confusing. Make your class name more descriptive.

Comment: Really thanks, it works. I already changed Frame to another name, you're right, it's a weird name. I just edited my main, so that the frame is set invisible for a short time:            frame.activePanel = new LoginPanel();
  frame.add(frame.activePanel);
  frame.setVisible(false);
  frame.setVisible(true);

  new Main();

Comment: @Geosearchef, `I just edited my main, so that the frame is set invisible for a short time` - NO!!! That is NOT the way to solve the problem!!! The login panel belongs to the frame class and so it should be created in the frame class. Don't take shortcuts!!!

Comment: You're right, but it dont want to write clear code, i judt wanted to write a little application very quick. I'll change it when i have the time.

Comment: @Geosearchef, `i judt wanted to write a little application very quick.` - why do you think it takes more time to write an application properly? Think of all the time you have wasted trying to debug the code because you did not write the code properly from the start. Spend more time with the up front design to do it properly and you will save far more time with debugging.